# Pycharm - Numpy dtypes int8 int32 are not showing

Tags: numpy, pycharm

Im learning numpy and derived types like `int8, int32`, etc are not showing in pycharm intellisense, only `int, intc` and similar are shown. In pycharm's python console it shows all the available types.

[image: screenshot from editor tab]

[image: screenshot from pycharm python console]

Comment: where they are not showing? Have you imported numpy and when writing "numpy.int" it does not suggest int32? Give some screenshot

Comment: @dankal444 I have attached screenshots from both editor and python console

Comment: Ok, now I see and I can reproduce this issue. But I'm afraid this is not the case for stackoverflow - best to make new issue on [pycharm issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)